# Migrate from openFeint to Gree platform

Tags: android, openfeint, gree

i should migrate from openfeint to gree platform. i downloaded gree sdk and when i import the sdk i get this error:

> Cannot nest 'oauth.signpost.Signpostttt.oauth.signpost.Signpost/src/main/java' inside        'oauth.signpost.Signpostttt.oauth.signpost.Signpost/src'. To enable the nesting exclude 'main/' from 'oauth.signpost.Signpostttt.oauth.signpost.Signpost/src'

i could not find the way to solve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: I know it's not quite the same problem, but I recommend doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12383194/360211 It helped me get gree building.

Comment: thanks, i realized that i try to import the libraries as existing android code but when i tried to import as existing project i got no errors