# Lots of errors in SDK sample project

Tags: android

I'm getting lots of errors in a sample project i imported, iv tried cleaning project and changing compiler level back and forth, but it hasn't helped, also tried adding support library.

The way I got sample was file> new> others> android project sample

Some of the errors i'm getting

Fragment Tabhost cannot be resolved to a type.

Fragment page adapter cannot be resolved to a type.

The import android.support.v13 cannot be resolved.

The method get count() of type action bar tab pager. tabadapter must override of implement a supertype method.

I haven't messed with it all the errors where there from when i opened it.

Comment: You need to add external Android support Jar to your class path. <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/11238533/2197087">See here.</a>

Comment: The v4.jar was selected all ready i clicked the other 2 options as well and still no good

Comment: Change: 
"import android.support.v13.app.FragmentActivity"
To:
"import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity"

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing support library. In order to install it:

- Right click your project
- Select Android Tools / Add support library...
- Follow the dialog steps

Comment: I have added support library all ready, could it be anything else

Comment: Which version? I'm guessing you may have added support v4 instead of v13, which seems the version your project is expecting.

Comment: The only option i have is support library revision 12.

Comment: Well, you could try and manually download it. http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/android-support/android-support-v13.jar.zip

Answer (score 0):

As the answer above states,
Add the missing libraries, which can be found at "sdk"/extras/android/support/v13/
and "sdk"/extras/android/support/v4/

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

I did this by adding external jars to my project.

1. Right click on project
2. Click on **Properties**
3. Select **Java Build Path**
4. Select the **Libraries** tab
5. Click on the **Add External Jars**... button
6. Browse to "sdk*"/extras/android/support/v4/
7. Select **android-support-v4**
8. Click open or enter

Do the same for v13 and the errors disappear.

*this is where your sdk is located.