# "FragmentTabHost cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: android, android-library

Just now am starting to build apps on android.I added ADT plugin form this site `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`
       Then I did File->new->other->Android->Android Sample Project->Support13Demos[Android Support Library]  think that this some demo so that i could learn something but its says "FragmentTabHost cannot be resolved to a type" in one of the files I had 2 more errors which i resolved by downloading the 2 jars android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v13.jar.but this error doesnt seem go i think these to need a jar i am finding it very difficult to get that.Any suggestions on this would be helpful.
     As am trying Android for the time please do tell if i have assumed/trying something wrong thanks

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/12383194/1651233?

Comment: @baraky  Thanks for ur info da.I was doing similar steps but i had downloaded 'android-support-v13.jar' and 'android-support-v4.jar' jars from google and trying so it didnt have FragmentTabHost i guess.Now after coping those jars from Android-sdk problem solved but there is 1 more error 'Call requires API level 17 (current min is 13): android.app.Fragment#getChildFragmentManager' probably i need to upgrade my Android-sdk will do it thanks