# How to check if GooglePlayServices is installed with Android less than 3.0 (FragmentActivity)

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying to add GooglePlayServices to my existing Android project (Android 2.3.3).
If I go to [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#AppPermissions) to see how to check if GooglePlayServices app is installed it uses FragmentActivity but it was added on Android 3.0. So How can I check for it in Android 2.2 for example?
Thanks!

Comment: its not really any different from using it in a regular activity. Besides, `FragmentActivity` can be used in 2.2 as it is part of the support library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In example you have pointed FragmentActivity comes from android support library v4. All you need to do is set the proper import not listed in this tutorial.

BTW. All those Google Play Services tutorials are totally messy. You totally don't need all those fragments. They are used only for interacting with user in case of some connectivity problems

Comment: And this is needed as well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164886/fragmentactivity-cannot-be-resolve-to-a-type