# The type android.support.v4.app.Fragment cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files, Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-support-library, android-facebook

i want to publish photo and text in facebook, for that i have used below code from the facebook reference site

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/link-to-your-native-app/#step6

i have copied all the code in my activity so code but in below line i am getting error

```
    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                        MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS);
```

here in this line i am getting error like **The type android.support.v4.app.Fragment cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files**

can anybody help me, how to resolve this, i think that it is because **android-support-v4.jar
** is also over here and it is in facebook sdk also,

Comment: I fixed this issues, 

1.Goto Project->Right click project->Android Tools->Add Support Library.

2. And Goto your Lib project(s)->Right Click->Android Tools->Add Support Library.

3. Finally, Clean all your projects.

Answer (score 12):

I resolved this issue using [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11238533/622391):

> If you are using eclipse and windows, here is how you can get rid of this error.
>
> Right click on your project folder->Build path-> Configure build path->
>
> Add External Jars -> select "android-support-v4.jar" file (It'll be located in Android 
>    "android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support")
>
> then click OK.