# Android project complaining "The type bolts.Task cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-support-library

I'm trying to go through the Parse [Mealspotting](https://parse.com/tutorials/mealspotting) tutorial, but after adding the Parse library I'm getting weird errors. I've found other similar errors while googling, but nothing that has worked. [Here's one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771395/the-type-android-support-v4-app-fragment-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indirectly-re) I also read to look at [Adding the Support Libraries](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html), but that didn't fix it.[image: Here's what I'm seeing in Eclipse]

Exact text is:

`Multiple markers at this line
    - The type bolts.Task cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    - The class file Task<?> contains a signature 'Ljava/util/Set<Lbolts/Task<*>.TaskCompletionSource;>;' ill-formed at 
     position 30`

I don't care about the support libraries or what devices the app will work on, all I want is for this to work so I can go through the tutorial. Has anyone dealt with this before?

I have also tried creating a project that only supports Kit Kat and removed the support libraries, but it's still throwing the same error.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try to add the bolts-android-1.1.3 lib in your project. You can find it in the Parse SDK zip file.

Comment: search bolts in your parse folder and add to your project

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure that you have the Parse library in your lib folder.

I had the same problem and solved it by adding the bolts-android-1.1.3.jar (right click on your project properties and then java build path , tab libraries, add jars or externals jars) that i found in Parse-1.7.1.

Then clean your project and it should work.