# Parse.com Notifications issue - Importing Parse-1.9.4.jar

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm having issues compiling Parse.com code for sending notifications to Android users using Eclipse

I have imported the Parse-1.9.4.jar into my project (libs folder), Also i've ensured I ticked the box in Order & Export.

```
//This is ok is found
Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxx", "xxxxxx");
```

But i'm still getting a red warning '**Configure Build Path**'

```
//This Line is causing issues
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

UPDATE: ERROR

Multiple markers at this line
    **- The type bolts.Task cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class** 
     files
    **- Line breakpoint:InboxActivity [line: 166] - onCreate(Bundle)**

Comment: androidstudio or eclipse?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it's eclipse

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26622547/android-project-complaining-the-type-bolts-task-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indir

Answer (score 0):

1)  right click your project.

2) select build path-->configure build path.

3)  update all the broken links in all  tabs.

4) Go to project-->clean [project will be found at top menu of eclipse.]

5) Clean your project.

Comment: What do you mean by "update all the broken links in all tabs."? thanks

Comment: did you seen any broken symbols?

Comment: No, I don't see broken symbols

Comment: then try  clean project and reopen eclipse

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - The type bolts.Task cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class 
  files
 - Line breakpoint:InboxActivity [line: 166] - onCreate(Bundle)

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26622547/android-project-complaining-the-type-bolts-task-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indir

Answer (score 0):

Put this on Gradle file (build.gradle)

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the bolts-android-1.1.3 lib in my project. You can find it in the Parse SDK zip file.

Comment: You don't need the zip file, just add bolts library to your gradle file. See my answer, let me know if works :)