# Trying to use the Google Maps demo code for Android, import FragmentActivity cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro). I am using the ADT bundle (I cleaned everything out and re-downloaded since encountering this problem). I used the SDK manager to install the Google Play Services. I am using SDK version 19 and platform version 4.4.2

I copied "google-play-services_lib" successfully, but got 2 "Unable to resolve target 'android-9'" messages.

I then created the maps demo project and got "Unable to resolve target 'android-16' (this confused me quite a bit, as I couldn't find any place where version 16 was even mentioned, it was either 19, 17, or 9) as well as a ton of unresolved imports. Looking at the Android tab of properties, I saw the reference had a red X next to it (it referenced ..\..\libproject\google-play-serviced_lib instead of ../google-play-services_lib). I updated the reference, getting rid of almost every unresolved import.

At this point I am still getting "The import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity cannot be resolved" in the file "SaveStateDemoActivity.java" (as well as a few other errors stemming from this problem). I'm not sure what my problem is, and there is no mention of any of this in the tutorial. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164886/fragmentactivity-cannot-be-resolve-to-a-type) is a somewhat related question, but it seems to be a very different situation. I'm also having a very difficult time understanding the best response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is a somewhat related question, but it seems to be a very different situation.

[This is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164886/fragmentactivity-cannot-be-resolve-to-a-type) to your problem. `FragmentActivity` (a subclass of `Activity`) is a class of the [`support library`](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html). This library is made to help developers manage application compatibility with older devices.

`Fragment` was introduced in `API 11 (Android 3.0 HoneyComb)`.

So if you want to make your app run on older devices `(API < 11)` you have to add this library to your project in order to use `FragmentActivity` class.

[Read this from the doc](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)